# Blank edit text area on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, meta

Trying to edit my own post on Meta, I found myself unable to do so. The text area for edit is completely blank, although all other edit interface remains in place. I did not try to enter something and save, because the original post is large and uses enough formatting, so restoring it will be not really easy. Here's what I mean:

[image: Initial post]

After clicking "edit":

[image: After clicking "edit"]

This reproduces on Brave (chromium-based browser) and Firefox. This does not reproduce on Meta questions, but does - on answers (both mine and somebody else's). Toggling a mode does not help. The text area behaves as really blank (I can enter everything and use formatting capabilities, but have no access to original content)

Comment: Probably related (MSE): [Empty editor when editing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383178)

Comment: Ough, sorry, haven't found it for some reason. Not related, but definitely dupe. UPD: Aha, it's 20 minutes old, I was searching for a dupe before another q was added...

Comment: No repro on Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119 or Safari 16.0 on Mac

Comment: It does not reproduce on my Chrome either.

Comment: One weird thing is that even though you've edited (right?) the answer itself is still visible in the screenshot with an editor also open. Does it appear under the answer? Or is it a collage of two screenshots?

Comment: Interesting: everything recovered now, I can edit my post again, and the bug does not reproduce any more.

Comment: @VLAZ it's not a collage, there are two different images, try clicking one of them... (I haven't even noticed that it looks like concatenation, fixed)

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry, I assumed it's a single image.

Comment: "*Interesting: everything recovered now,*" Might have been a temporary hiccup. I won't be surprised.

Comment: This was useful for me! I learned that it was not my fault with all that dead formatting, but a [new editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) with "rich text" mode, and discovered a setting to disable this and get my markdown back by default... Hope it won't be added to SO anytime soon.

Comment: The changes to the new editor that likely caused this were rolled back about two hours ago, so it's likely that this issue has resolved itself. Please let me know if that's not the case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. I posted an explanation on a Meta SE report for the same issue.

> The root cause of this issue was fixed in a release earlier this week.
>
> The bug was introduced during a refactor of how we initialize the new Stacks Editor across various web pages. The intent of this refactor was to reduce the number of invocation paths and standardize on a base set of features to enable (one being the new Markdown Preview mode).
>
> There were subtle differences in how our Teams product and various pages on the public site were using these methods, and this led to a blind spot in our testing with regards to editing content with the new editor.
>
> Moving forward, we will now have the proper tests in place that cover this scenario (among others) and are working to surface the failures earlier in the development process to help prevent releasing regressions like this.
>
> Apologies for the oversight. I'll take two demerits as punishment.

[Empty editor when editing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383178/empty-editor-when-editing-an-answer/383329#383329)